# Carry over variable value to new method

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I can't seem to get my method working without having to reset the variable to a value of 'null' or new Object. What I need is to have the user input carry over into the next method.

```
public static void addItem ()
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    String desc, id, str="";
    double price = 0, setUpPrice = 0, unitCost = 0, inventoryCost = 0;
    int stock = 0, demand = 0;
    Product product  = new Product();


    System.out.print("Please enter product description between 3 to 10 characters...: ");
    desc = console.next();
    desc = desc.toLowerCase();
    product.setName(desc);


    /*if (desc.length < 3 || desc.length > 10)
    {
        System.out.print("This Input is incorrect, Please try again.");
    }*/
    System.out.print("Please enter price in $ : ");
    price = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter set up price. $ : ");
    setUpPrice = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter unit- cost. $ : ");
    unitCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter the inventory cost. $ : ");
    inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter the amount in stock : ");
    stock = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the demand of the product : ");
    demand = console.nextInt();


    // need code here to repeat the fuction again if y is pressed.
    // if n is pressed need to return to inventory management interface.

}

public static void prodData ()
{
    Product product = new Product();

    System.out.println("The information for the product is : ");
    System.out.println("Product description : "+product.getName());
}
```

Comment: By carry over into new method, so you mean you want to pass it as a parameter, perhaps?

Comment: In general, in OO programming, the best solution for something like this would be to declare a class that has private instance fields. Then a method could set an instance field, and the "next method" could read it.  However, your actual question is quite short on specifics, so I don't really know what you're referring to by "input" or "next method" or anything.

Comment: sorry, so what im trying to get at is from the code the user enters an input in the addItem() area, i then want to display what they entered in there into the prodData() area, but at the moment i have the product product = new product in both the additem() and the prodData() which means that the user input is taken away

Comment: In this case, you could have `addItem` return a `Product` (instead of being `void`), and pass the `Product` as a parameter to `prodData` (instead of creating a new one in `prodData`).  Then whoever calls these methods would be responsible for saving the result of `addItem` and passing it to `prodData`.  That would be one mechanism.  The OO solution I alluded to would be another good solution.  Global variables are one of the worst solutions, as you will learn when you start learning about software design and writing more complex programs.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your product var as global and access as follows

```
    public static  Product product; 

public static void addItem () {
    product  = new Product();
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    String desc, id, str="";
    double price = 0, setUpPrice = 0, unitCost = 0, inventoryCost = 0;
    int stock = 0, demand = 0;

    System.out.print("Please enter product description between 3 to 10 characters...: ");
    desc = console.next();
    desc = desc.toLowerCase();
    product.setName(desc);


    /*if (desc.length < 3 || desc.length > 10)
    {
        System.out.print("This Input is incorrect, Please try again.");
    }*/
    System.out.print("Please enter price in $ : ");
    price = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter set up price. $ : ");
    setUpPrice = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter unit- cost. $ : ");
    unitCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter the inventory cost. $ : ");
    inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter the amount in stock : ");
    stock = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the demand of the product : ");
    demand = console.nextInt();

    // need code here to repeat the fuction again if y is pressed.
    // if n is pressed need to return to inventory management interface.

}

public static void prodData () {
    System.out.println("The information for the product is : ");
    System.out.println("Product description : "+product.getName());
}
```

Comment: okay thank you for that answer, I've added your bit but now I'm getting and error of java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: @RaznishSmith can you share the stack trace ?